One-sample Student's T-test p-value in Clickhouse?
Clickhouse provides a two-sample Student's t-test function studentTTest, while there is no one-sample t-test function. Is there a way to do one-sample t-test and output p-value directly in Clickhouse without querying data into Python?

no way, AFAIK, try create issue in https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues

You are right. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/studentttest is for two populations. Please create a feature request for this - https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/new?assignees=&labels=feature&projects=&template=20_feature-request.md&title=
